# Chrome fails to start on paid python anywhere account

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, pythonanywhere

Following the latest advice on python anywhere regarding using default ChromeDriver: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/selenium/

I have the following code fragment:

```
if dev_server=='Y':
    service = Service(executable_path=Path(cwd,'chromedriver.exe'))
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging']) 
if dev_server=='Y':
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service,options=options)      
else:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

NOTE dev_server is not 'Y'

I receive the following error:
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
(unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
(The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/chromium is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
#0 0x563e173ffe89

Please explain what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You linked to the help page that has example code that works, but do not appear to be following the advice there.